# Php and MySQL: Dissect fullname string into first, middle and last name and stored it in variables

Tags: php, mysql

is there a way that I can dissect a person full name, that is pulled from mysql database into first name, middle name and last name and stored it into php variables? thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Use `explode` function to separate the `firstname`,`middlename`,and `lastname` and store it in variables, this is demo.

```
$name = "first middle last";
$arr = explode(" ",$name);
$first = $arr[0];
$middle= $arr[1];
$last= $arr[2];
```

Comment: But... "Yogesh Suthar" would give `$first == 'Yogesh'` and `$last == ''` :P

Comment: @Jon Yeah its true. But OP has mentioned that it will be combination of `firstname middlename lastname`.

Comment: I know, just wanted to point out that if a middle name doesn't exist, it won't work for him; but there really isn't a better solution based on what OP gave. =] (Besides, it's April Fool's day, some humor needs to be injected here)

Comment: Hello sorry for late reply, thanks for your suggestions.. yeah this problem really give me hard time to figure it out because there are lot of names in my database that have two first names and two last names, anyway all I did was to manually separated the 7300+ records names (very fun!) in excel...